# Div is not filling up the page

Tags: html, css

I've created two small blocks but i does not start from the screen edges but it takes space from left and right and top too. here is my code

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>    
  <div id="block1"></div>    
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#header
{
    background:#1A2328;
    height:150px;
}

#block1
{
height:600px;
background:#657;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mV2TB/)

Comment: Any reason for the unaccept after almost a couple of years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reset the default user agent stylesheet.

**Here is a basic example.**

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vv6LK/)

I suggest looking at a **CSS reset**, see [**Eric Meyer's here**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 2):

Body by default has some `margin` and `padding`. Reset it like below:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **Working DEMO Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/h7TN8/

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;     
}
```